# Is my MacBook replacement screen a genuine Apple product?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Model: 2017 Two-Thunderbolt Port One.

Hi All! I had an issue in my MacBook display (product fault) and gave it to the local authorised dealer to replace the screen for me. Looks like I have been give a plastic lid instead of an original part from Apple. I felt the texture of the screen was different. This lid is actually heavier & thicker than the original one I had (and said this to Apple in the post-service survey) when I collected it too. Now the screen is bad in showing colours (after few months) and also has different issues like lines showing.

All the experts here, do Apple make these cheap, heavy plastic lids? or have I been scammed where they had kept the original one that came for me and has given me a cheap knock-off?

Thanks for your kind help guys!

Comment: Apple *does* use refurbished parts and systems for repairs. **BUT** they are genuine Apple parts and should look and work identical to the parts they replaced. I would be concerned about that "repair."

Comment: If it's convenient I would suggest taking it to an Apple store. They can determine if the repair was done correctly. If not, they will make things right.